# How to update repeater field if I have the array key to it?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I've found this code which is supposed to update a repeater field in ACF Wordpress. My repeater has 3 columns. I need to update only a certain field from one column in the repeater. How to do that with this code:

```php
// save a repeater field value
$field_key = "field_3424324234";
$value = array(
    array(
        "sub_field_1"   => "Foo",
        "sub_field_2"   => "Bar"
    )
);
update_field( $field_key, $value, $post_id );
```

I need to say that I don't have a PRO license and I can't use update_sub_field().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer my question bellow. I used a function a little different than update_field, called update_sub_field. For this to work you need to have ACF Pro 5+. Jordi Nebot answer helped me a bit, but in my case I needed to add some extra variable(`$post_id`). So here it is, hoping will help someone:

```php
update_sub_field( array("repeater_field_key", $row+1, "repeater_sub_field_key"), $new_value, $post_id);
```

I added `$row+1` because `$row` number count starts from `1`, when `$row` start position starts from `0` when looping through repeater. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: I've done the same but is it possible to iterate the child repeater? Mine only updates the first row of the child repeater so it's overwriting itself.

Comment: @Rob, yes it's possible. It updates only the first row because you don't use a loop to iterate over the whole array of rows. You can use a regular `while` loop. An example can be found here in the docs https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_sub_field/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to update a subfield inside a *Repeater*, you should be using [`update_sub_field`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_sub_field/) instead of `update_field`.

I assume (by your snippet) you're not iterating the repeater with `have_rows`, so let's say you want to update `sub_field_2` in your third row, it would be something like:

```
$subfield = 'sub_field_2';
$row = 3;
$new_value = 'The new value of the field';
update_sub_field( array( $field_key, $row, $sub_field ), $new_value, $post_id );
```

**Edit:** I've missed the `$post_id` param in my answer. Thank you @Anonymous for making me notice this.

I hope this helps!

Comment: And $subfield = 'sub_field_2', applies the same to me or do I have to change the 'sub_field_' with what I have?

Comment: I get this " Call to undefined function update_sub_field() "

Comment: Of course, `sub_field_2`  should be the name of the subfield you want to update. (I've just used `sub_field_2` because of your code).

Comment: @Anonymous if you get a _undefined function_ error and you have ACF properly installed and active then it's because you're using a version prior to 5.0.0 in which case I'd recommend you to update ACF.

Comment: I think that's a premium version which I don't have. I have 4.4.3 and the updated would be to 4.4.7

Comment: how would the code look if I use have_rows loop? Would I use again the update_sub_field()? Because I don't have a Pro version of ACF. Isn't there an alternative to update_sub_field()?

Comment: Please @Anonymous, check the [Inside have_rows() loop](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_sub_field/) section of documentation. If you can't get a legal copy of ACF Pro check [update_field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/) docs. ACF documentation is easy to understand and full of code samples.

Comment: Thanks Jordi Nebot, but I found my own solution and I will post it as the answer.

Comment: @JordiNebot I've done the same but is it possible to iterate the child repeater? Mine only updates the first row of the child repeater so it's overwriting itself.